# Using Spring MVC to display values from DTOs to jsp

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations, dto

I have a DTO with setters and getters of the attributes of my table. In the jsp page, there is a table whose values I have to populate by using a controller such that values from the setters in my dto get displayed in the jsp. Please help. Its very urgent!

Comment: What have you tried and what problems have you encountered so far? Have you studied the Spring documentation (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Put the dto in the model map within the controller.
In the jsp use a for each loop that iterates of that model attribute -- or more specific over the list wihtin the dto that have contains the data for the rows.

---

*If you need more specific help, then extend your question with the source code you already have tryed. (that is the normal way stack overflow works)*